# Match a Word which is not followed by a parenthesis for the rest of the string

Tags: java, regex, string-parsing

I have a string like so:

```
((blah blah AND) (blah AND blah) AND good) AND Zero AND (Blah AND Blah)
```

I want to match only those "AND's" which are outside any parenthesis, that is only the OUTER AND's

The regex I used was: AND(?!))

And the result was:

*I thought of uploading a screenshot of the result here, but SO doesn't allow me to unless*

It only doesn't match the AND's where the ')' is immediately followed but it matches the rest of the AND's.

Again, I would ideally want a regex to match only the AND's which occur outside of any parenthesis, that is the outer AND's.

Note that I am implementing this in Java and its regex implementation doesn't support recursive regex. So is the reason that I am attempting this sloppy workaround

I am looking for a better and more robust solution for this.

Comment: you might want to look into using something like ANTLR which does support nested parenthesis.

Comment: What's the purpose of matching `AND`s? Are you trying to replace it with something else?

Comment: I just want to MATCH the AND's outside, and replace them with something else.

Comment: What are the possible inputs? can the AND that is outside any parentheses come before the parentheses?

Comment: You could reduce the text before applying the regex: if(s.contains(")"){
        String t = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(")"), s.length()-1);
    }

Comment: SME_Dev, I don't understand, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Stack would work well here. You can simulate one by setting a variable to count the parenthesis. For left parenthesis +1 and for right -1. If you find an AND and the parenthesis count is 0 then you're all set.

Comment: Yep, that is kind of what I have eventually implemented, although not exactly. I am processing the whole thing by using a modified version of the BODMAS expression evaluation algorithm. It worked!